# Does Power Nap allow an Apple TV to access media on a sleeping Mac?

Tags: macos, power-nap

Do I have to wake up a Power Nap enabled Mac to stream media off of it or can I leave it sleeping?

Comment: I believe Power Nap is only relevant if you use flash-based storage. Are you streaming off an SSD drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work on my AppleTV 2 and MacBook Air.

Last night I turned on the AppleTV to browse my main library on a Mac Mini and the MacBook Air library showed up as well, even though the lid was closed and the computer was asleep.

I have not experimented enough to know if this works with the power adapter unplugged.

This was a very pleasant, but apparently undocumented, feature to discover. Perhaps it arrived in the most recent AppleTV update.